# ngIf to display or not <p>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, if-statement

Just a quick question about Angular (I'm not familiar with this framework yet and didn't find a success answer).

I want to display or not a

example sentence

according to the result of a ngIf.

```
<div *ngFor="let tip of tips;let i=index;" class="alert {{getBackground(tip)}}" role="alert">
<h4 class="alert-heading">{{tip.title}} <span class="alert-date">{{getDate(tip.date)}}</span></h4>
<p>{{tip.details}}</p>
<p ng-if="{{getBackground(tip)}}==alert-danger">Example</p>
```

The {{getBackground(tip)}} expression give me a String, which I'm trying to test.

Is that the correct way ?

Thanks a lot !

Matthieu

Comment: When you try it, does it work?

Comment: Nop it doesn't !

Comment: Well it's not the correct way then, is it?

Comment: Which angular version? You've tagged as angularjs which is 1.x. 2+ is just angular. It's not clear here since you use the syntax of both in your post.

Comment: @JJJ Then it's not the correct way I guess !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `*ngIf` not `ng-if` here, And compare without `{{....}}`

```
<p *ngIf="getBackground(tip) == 'alert-danger'">Example</p>
```

Comment: @RishiRaut I did not downvoted your answer but yes I upvoted it. Matthieu mark it as accepted answer

Comment: @Red : May be he is doing this, inside `getBackground` function. Thanks for revert downvote. But you can upvote too.

Comment: I didnt downvote, but I wont upvote either. Don't ask for upvotes as this might cause you downvotes instead .. Upvotes are here to show that the awnser is relevant and informative or what ever. You are saying 'maybe you should'. Which is basicly not an good awnser. Because its an awnser of guesses.

Comment: @Red : Thanks for your comment, I updated my answer. !my English is good.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking equality for a string so you have to put quotes around the string. So the code will become

```
<p ng-if="{{getBackground(tip)}}=='alert-danger'">Example</p>
```